# DELETE FROM NOT IN not working with PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, notin

I have an array like this

```
array([0]=> 'email@email.com', [1]=> 'email2@email.com', [2]=> 'email3@email.com');
```

I also have a table with hunders of emails on it.

I want to be able to delete all of these emails apart from the ones that are in the array.

I tried this code but nothing happens:

```
    $emails = join(', ', $emails);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE customer_id='".$id."' AND email NOT IN(".$emails.")";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: You need to convert array to textual form like @Omesh proposed in his answer

Comment: I hope you are certain that the array elements cannot contain SQL.  Otherwise, look into [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function in php to import covert array to string.

Also need to enclose string values of email in quotes:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE customer_id='".$id."' AND 
        email NOT IN('".implode("','",$emails)."')";
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
$emails = implode("', '", $emails);
$sql = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE customer_id='".$id."' AND email NOT IN('".$emails."')";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: @PeterStuart The difference is in the `implode` and that it will encapsulate each email address in single quotes nicely. +1 (I read it three times before I noticed the difference)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes:

```
$emails = implode("', '", $emails);
$sql = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE customer_id='".$id."' AND email NOT IN('".$emails."')";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains literals, but these aren't each individually being surrounded by quotes for your IN list.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that you're not wrapping the individual emails with quotes in the query. mysql_error should have picked that up though surely?

```
$emails = join('", "', $emails);
$sql = 'DELETE FROM emails WHERE customer_id="'.$id.'" AND email NOT IN("'.$emails.'")';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Try echoing out $sql and see what you get (post it here if it doesnt make much sense).

EDIT: How dare 2 people post the same answer as me while I'm typing my answer! >:|

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
$emails = join(',', $emails);
To avoid comma in last ,
$emails=trim($emails,',');
$sql = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE customer_id='".$id."' AND email NOT IN(".$emails.")";
$res = $this->db->query($sql);
```